# Get position of node socket in python

Tags: python, node-editor

Is there a way to get the position (x/y coordinates) of a socket on a node in the node editor?

I'm working on auto layout functionality and having the actual socket position would make it much more useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully a reputable source - Node Wrangler source: [Add Reroutes](https://github.com/gregzaal/node_wrangler/blob/master/node_wrangler.py#L2319) operator

If you disregard the trick to calculate the width of a hidden node (that doesn't work anyway), as well as reroute-specific business, the code boils down to:

```py
x = node.location.x
y = node.location.y
width = node.width
x = node.location.x + width + 20.0
if node.type != 'REROUTE':
    y -= 35.0
y_offset = -22.0
loc = x, y
```

And I would refactor this as:

```py
X_OFFSET = 20.0
Y_START_OFFSET = -35.0
Y_OFFSET = -22.0

for i in range(number_of_outputs):
    x = node.location.x + node.width + X_OFFSET
    y = node.location.y + Y_START_OFFSET + i*Y_OFFSET
```

Now you only need to adjust the `X_OFFSET` and `Y_START_OFFSET` so they point exactly to outputs as opposed to right from the outputs. As for the inputs, they are aligned to the bottom left, so the formula is similar, just that instead of using `width` for `x`, you use `height` for `y`... Except `height` actually doesn't work for some reason so I decided to use `dimensions` attribute instead:

### <kbd>F3</kbd> `Delete without sockets`

[image]

```py
import bpy
from collections import namedtuple

the_id = "delete_without_sockets"

X_OFFSET = -1.0
Y_TOP = -34.0
Y_BOTTOM = 16.0
Y_OFFSET = 22.0

# 2 offsets 
VEC_BOTTOM = 28.0
VEC_TOP = 32.0

Reroute = namedtuple('Reroute', ['x', 'y', 'type'])


def is_hidden(socket):
    return socket.hide or not socket.enabled


def is_tall(node, socket):
    if socket.type != 'VECTOR':
        return False
    if socket.hide_value:
        return False
    if socket.is_linked:
        return False
    if node.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED' and socket.identifier == 'Subsurface Radius':
        return False  # an exception confirms a rule?
    return True


def main(C):
    node = C.active_node
    nodes = C.material.node_tree.nodes
    ins, outs = [], []

    x = node.location.x + node.dimensions.x + X_OFFSET
    y = node.location.y + Y_TOP    
    for output in node.outputs:
        if is_hidden(output):
            continue
        ins.append(Reroute(x, y, output.type))
        y -= Y_OFFSET

    x = node.location.x
    y = node.location.y - node.dimensions.y + Y_BOTTOM
    for input in reversed(node.inputs):
        if is_hidden(output):
            continue
        tall = is_tall(node, input)
        y += VEC_BOTTOM*tall
        outs.append(Reroute(x, y, input.type))
        y += Y_OFFSET + VEC_TOP*tall
        
    for x, y, type in ins + outs:
        n = nodes.new('NodeReroute')
        n.location = x, y
        n.inputs[0].type = type
            
    bpy.ops.node.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    node.select = True
    bpy.ops.node.delete()


class DeleteWithoutSockets(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Delete a node but add reroutes where its sockets have been"""
    bl_idname = f"object.{the_id}"
    bl_label = "Delete without sockets"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_node is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(DeleteWithoutSockets.bl_idname, text=DeleteWithoutSockets.bl_label)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(DeleteWithoutSockets)
    bpy.types.NODE_MT_view.append(menu_func)
    setattr(bpy.types.WindowManager, f"{the_id}_cls", DeleteWithoutSockets)
    setattr(bpy.types.WindowManager, f"{the_id}_fun", menu_func)


def unregister():
    oldclass = getattr(bpy.types.WindowManager, f"{the_id}_cls")
    oldfunc = getattr(bpy.types.WindowManager, f"{the_id}_fun")
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(oldclass)
    bpy.types.NODE_MT_view.remove(oldfunc)
    delattr(bpy.types.WindowManager, f"{the_id}_cls")
    delattr(bpy.types.WindowManager, f"{the_id}_fun")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        unregister()
    except AttributeError:
        register()
```

Comment: This is insanely great. Just a note, for example with the Mapping node, it will not correctly position the sockets relative to the Loc / Rot / Scale controls

Comment: @NoobCat aah, good catch, vector inputs are larger, fortunately you can detect that...

Comment: @NoobCat see edit - I added additional logic for vectors (I went through all vanilla vectors and found only a peculiar exception for Subsurface Radius in Principled BSDF), as well as I separate the logic of creating a list of input/output socket positions from populating them with reroutes.

Comment: I have studied your function well. It is really very useful, it is a good starting point to work on any changes. By guidelines I can not say "Thanks", so I will not do it, but I will do it with my thoughts

Comment: @NoobCat Thanks

Comment: Is this broken in Blender 3.2?  I get the error `AttributeError: Writing to ID classes in this context is not allowed: Shader Nodetree, NodeTree datablock, error setting NodeReroute.location` when trying to set the location of any node.  NB: it works in the console window, but not in a script (and I'm not trying it in an Operator, just a plain script)

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug it seems you answered yourself, it works, hard to say without seeing your code why it doesn't work in your specific script.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the [location of a Node](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79b/bpy.types.Node.html#bpy.types.Node.location) as well as the width and height, but the position of the socket does not seem to be available. This is likely to be because nodes can be in collapsed or expanded states and so a particular socket may or may not be visible at any given time.

You should be able to get pretty far knowing the dimensions and location of the node itself though. You know that all inputs are on the left side and all outputs on the right, and you can find out [which nodes are linked to which](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79b/bpy.types.NodeLink.html#bpy.types.NodeLink), so you could do a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) and arrange the nodes with some minimum amount of spacing.

Comment: I think this leads to a big problem. Nodes have different socket positions, just look at the difference in socket input positions between an Image node and a Principled BSDF. It really seems somewhat unlikely. Unless you create a register (A dictionary?) Of all nodes with all their socket locations