# How to hide_viewport object per execution?

Tags: python

I want to set `hide_viewport=False` when it runs the script.
Every time I run the script it should cycle between objects, only one object per execution.

E.g.

If I run the script 1 time then `Suzanne` should be visible and if 2 time I run the script `Suzanne.001` should be visible and other objects should be hidden.

[image]

Comment: oh so u want to cycle to the next in the list of the selected collection?

Comment: Yes, one object per execution.

Comment: A simple [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) should do the trick. Something like "for objects in selected: hide object, do other things", and perhaps show object at the end if you don't need to keep it hidden.

Comment: I want to cycle object per execution

Answer (score 3):

In theoretical terms, you need to maintain state between script executions. In practice this can be achieved by e.g. saving the last object altered to a file, or to a text-block inside Blender. Or to a custom property, or if you don't want it to be saved neither in .blend file or outside of it, you could just assign to a type like I do here using the `types.WindowManager`:

[Get position of node socket in python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/252856/60486)

Or, and it's a little bit of a crazy idea, modify self. What possibly could go wrong*?

```py
previous=None

from bpy import context as C, data as D
line_1 = C.edit_text.lines[0]
objects = (o for o in D.objects)
if previous is None:
    ob = next(objects)
else:
    D.objects[previous].hide_render = False
    for ob in objects:
        if ob.name == previous:
            ob = next(objects, None)
            break
if ob is not None:
    ob.hide_render = True
previous = ob and ob.name
line_1.body = f"{previous=}"
C.edit_text.from_string(C.edit_text.as_string())  # refresh
```

[image]

*- [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I love the over-the-top solution ! I would have gone with custom properties, since they're de facto supported by Blender but this is great. After all, achieving consistent save / load of state is one of the first goals of programming, so it's only natural there are many, many ways to achieve this. Cheers

Comment: lol i didn't know you can run the script to change the script itself XD